# Vue2-editor и Quill image-resize-module

Tags: vue.js

При использования `quill-image-resize-module` в `vue2-editor` возникает ошибка:

> Unable to import module

Comment: Непонятно, где вопрос, где ответ. Опишите вопрос и отделите, пожалуйста, ответ от вопроса. Возможно вам подскажут и другие методы решения.

Comment: Я описал простой и самый быстрый способ исправить файлы в уже установленном пакете quill-image-resize-module,
и не мучиться поисками ошибки целый день и более (как я сам)))
------------------
вопрос-ответ одинаковый, потому что суть не меняется - подсказка, облегчающая жизнь, А вот когда в выдаче поиска стоит хоть один ответ - люди посмотрят - собственно как с вами наверное и было)))))
---------------
да - немного не в формате - я не мега_профи - уж извините)))

Comment: Так-то да, но может вы объясните, почему нельзя использовать привычное `npm i quill-image-resize-vue --save`?

Comment: Да все верно - и я исправил решение внизу ( просто вчера у меня почему-то webpack выдавал ошибку и я просто написал вариант для "ленивых"
НО поступил неверно - так как NODE постоянно будет "возвращать" исходное состояние папки quill-image-resize-module (если устанавливать еще другие модули quill)

Comment: Вы только не забывайте свои ответы галками отмечать.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузите реально исправленные и рабочие файлы с [quill-image-resize-vue](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/quill-image-resize-vue):

Этот пакет можно просто установить 
npm i --save quill-image-resize-vue
Тогда модуль вызываем из этой новой папки

```
import { VueEditor,Quill } from 'vue2-editor'
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-vue';
import { ImageDrop } from 'quill-image-drop-module';

Quill.register("modules/imageDrop", ImageDrop);
Quill.register("modules/imageResize", ImageResize);

export default {
  name: 'MainForm',
  components: { VueEditor},
  data() {
    return {
      content: '<h2>I am Example</h2>',
      editorSettings: {
        modules: {
          imageDrop: true,
          imageResize: {},
        }
      }
    }
  },
 // ...code
}
```